# Android: Retrofit: 3 methods to one without change client's code?

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
```

The Android client can send to server then next http requests:

```
GET /api/profiles.json
GET /api/profiles.json?page=1
GET /api/profiles.json?page=1&count=10
```

Fields: "**page**", "**count**" are not required.

I write 3 methods on interface:

```
public interface RestClient {

    @GET("/api/profile.json")
    Call<List<Profile>> getProfilesList();

    @GET("/api/profile.json")
    Call<List<Profile>> getProfilesList(@Query("page") int page);

    @GET("/api/profile.json")
    Call<List<Profile>> getProfilesList(@Query("page") int page, @Query("count") int count);
}
```

On client code (3 activites) call every of this method:

```
public class MyActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
...
ProfileService.getProfilesList(2, 3, new Callback<List<Profile>>() {...})
...
}
```

second activity:

```
public class MyActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
ProfileService.getProfilesList(2, new Callback<List<Profile>>() {...})
 ...
}
```

and third activity:

```
public class MyActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
...
ProfileService.getProfilesList(new Callback<List<Profile>>() {...})
...
}
```

OK. All client's code work fine.

But I want to create only one method `getProfilesList()` in interface RestClient.
And this does not affect to client's code. Not change anything ia client's code (**MyActivity1, MyActivity3, MyActivity3**)

Is it possible in Retrofit?

Comment: There's already a method called `getProfilesList()` in RestClient...

Comment: What is the problem with your current implementation?

Comment: If in interface RestClient stay  only one method: " Call<List<Profile>> getProfilesList(@Query("page") int page, @Query("count") int count);" - as result client code has compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing any code in the activities, it is **not possible**. You cannot call the method which hasn't been declared. Since you've used different methods in the activities, you must declare them.

Comment: Is it possible create method with infinity params (3 dots)? Something like this : "@GET("/api/profile.json")
    Call<List<Profile>> getProfilesList(Object ... params);  ?